# How to connect node.js to connect with local (SQL Server Express) mdf file

Tags: node.js, sql-server-express

I am new to node.js and wanted to connect my SQL Server (Express edition `.mdf` file) database which is running on my laptop. But I can't connect to my local `.mdf` database file.

Please help. Here is below my code snippet I use to connect to the local database:

```
function GETdata(callback) {
    var sql = require('mssql');  
    var setUp =  'DataSource=C:\Users\CRUSER\Documents\example.mdf;IntegratedSecurity=True;Connect Timeout=30'; 
    var connection =  new  sql.ConnectionPool(setUp);
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.query('SELECT * FROM PRODUCT',function(err, recordset)
        {
            callback(recordset);
        });
    });
```

Thanks
Elisabeth

Comment: "Couldn't connect" is not enough - please provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Requires Node.js 4 or newer.

```
npm install mssql

const sql = require('mssql')

async () => {
    try {
        const pool = await sql.connect('mssql://username:password@localhost/database')
        const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
        console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but it results in error :( . Syntax error : Unexpected token  { . Any clue what i did wrong...2. Also i am trying connect sqlexpress on my local laptop with windows authentication, not with username and pwd .Thanks Q.Elisabeth